# How to use cognito persistent unauthenticated credentials with a Api Gateway autogenerated Java SDK?

Tags: java, sdk, aws-api-gateway, amazon-cognito

With android I'm able to use `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider`, which stores everything in SharedPreferences.  I *think* I basically need to roll my own `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` with my own storage, but then how do I make it work with the api gateway autogenerated sdk?

Edit:  It looks like my own version of `CognitoCachingCredentialsProvider` needs to implement `AWSCredentialsProvider`, as that's what the java autogenerated SDK is looking for.